# how to combine two arrays in php?

Tags: encoding, key, decoding

I am having one array. For example :

```
array('a'=>'abc','b'=>'pqr','c'=>'xyz');
```

fron this i have encoded the key 'c'
now i am getting encoded value for this key.

next i need to put this encoded value in place of the original value of encoded key...

example i wnt output like this :

```
array('a'=>'abc','b'=>'pqr','c'=>H162);
```

please anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
$array1 = array('a'=>'abc','b'=>'pqr','c'=>'xyz');
$array2 = array('xyz'=>'test'); 
foreach($array1 as $key=>$element){
    if(array_key_exists($element, $array2)){
       $array1[$key] = $array2[$element]; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a value to element 'c' of the array. e.g.

```
$arr = array('a'=>'abc','b'=>'pqr','c'=>'xyz');
print_r($arr);
$arr['c'] = 'H162';
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

array_merge — Merge one or more arrays

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to change the value of 'c' and you know the key, you can simply call something like this

```
$your_array['c'] = NEW_VALUE
```

But this hasn't something to do with combining arrays. If you wan't to combine 2 arrays have a look at http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score 0):

Very broad question. I put an example with numbers, several encoding/decoding methods exist for strings.

First, define your encode/decode functions. (Note: In this example i work with positive numbers. You  could write you own encoding methods for strings). When you access your items, you must always know whether the value is encoded or not, so we always represent encoded numbers as negative numbers, and we assume negative numbers are encoded numbers. (For strings you can precede normal strings with "0" and encoded strings with "1" for example. Other methods exist.)

```
//Very simple functions, should be complex functions.
function encode($x) { return - $x * 2; }
function decode($x) { return - $x / 2; }
```

Now imagine an array:

```
$arr = array('a'=>123,'b'=>456,'c'=>789);
```

To encode the 'c':

```
$arr['c'] = encode($arr['c']);
```

...or encoding all items in your array:

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
   $arr[$key] = encode($arr[$key]);
```

For accessing the array members:

```
function getArrayMember($key)
{
if ($arr[$key] < 0)            //This is an encoded number...
    return decode($arr[$key]); //...decode it.
else                           //Normal numbers...
    return $arr[$key];         //...return as is.
}
```

This was for numbers. You could implement or find suitable encoding/decoding methods for strings.